# What do " ○" and "•" mean in "九○年", "ニ○•三パーセント", etc.?

Tags: meaning

This is from one of the reading comprehensions of *An Integrated Approach to Intermediate Japanese*.

> 九○年にはニ○•三パーセントだったが、ニ○○四年にはニ七•六パーセントだった

What are the ○ and • supposed to mean?? They were used in multiple sentences, mostly the ones where percentages were mentioned.

Comment: You used the character ○ (U+25CB) which is named "white circle", but the correct character is 〇 (U+3007) which is "ideographic number zero" (considered to be a kanji).

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't sure how it was pronounced so I just wrote "maru" on my keyboard to get a similar one. How are the they(〇 and •) pronounced?

Comment: On the Windows Japanese IME, U+3007 can be obtained from れい or ゼロ, because it effectively means 零.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are zeros and decimal points.

"In 90, it was 20.3 percent; in 2004, it was 27.6 percent."

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why did they use the ○ instead of 十?

Comment: @Meerfallthedewott They don't use ○ instead of 十, they use ○ to mean zero. It's used when writing out a number digit by digit using kanji instead of arabic numerals.

Comment: @Christer The meaning is pretty similar between 90 and 9-0, and it seems a bit unusual for years. What would be the motivation behind writing numbers as individual digits using kanji as opposed to using either of the alternatives (90, 九十)? I would understand that in the case of scores or ID numbers, but why use it for ordinal numbers as well?

Comment: @natiiix I would think this is a stylistic choice.  Given that percentages are being written in this hybrid style, editorially it might be seen as having a cleaner feel.  While I'm not 100% (excuse the pun) sure about this, it seems to me that calendar years are typically written using Arabic numerals.  So, if you're going to adopt this style, writing 九○年 instead of 90年 doesn't seem like such a strange choice.  Were it written as 九十年, I would probably be confused wondering whether they were talking about 90 years or the year 1990 (given the context).

Comment: @A.Ellett I think it's more understandable for percentages because you often have a decimal part and with that, I can understand it. However, for years, it just seems a bit weird to me. Wait, did they mean 1990? I just assumed it was the year 90 of the first century, or relative to a certain era/emperor. My problem with using ○ here is that it looks extremely out-of-place. On Linux, at least, it's tiny compared to other kanji, virtually idential to the full-stop period used in Japanese, just a bit higher (or the ° degrees symbol, but lower), making it look very much unlike any other kanji.

Comment: They mean 1990. It is an abbreviation for 一九九〇, which is practically never written as 千九百九十 when we are talking about the Gregorian calendar. Hence it is written as 九〇 and not 九十.
> it looks extremely out-of-place.
As mentioned in a comment above, ○ (U+25CB), "white circle", may be rendered as quite a tiny circle, but the correct character 〇 (U+3007), "ideographic number zero", is likely to be rendered nicely in your environment. That said, computer fonts are hard because Unicode is multilinguistic by its nature.